# Update query insert if I want to edit row in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I created a page, where I can easily update or insert data. It actually works, but if I click on the edit button, then I close the modal, then I add new data, it updates the previous data instead of inserting a new row.  But if I refresh a page, then I update a row, it works. How can I solve this problem?

**index.php**:

```
<form method="post" id="insert_form">
  <label><b>Name:</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" readonly required />
  <br />
  <label><b>Description:</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="hu" id="hu" class="form-control"></textarea>
  <br />
  <label><b>Cégek:</b></label>
  <select name="company[]" id="company" multiple>
  <?php
      while($row = $huResult2->fetch_array()) {
  ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['company_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['company_name'];?></option>
  <?php
      }
  ?>
  </select>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="data_id" id="data_id" />
  <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>

<script>
  $('#add').click(function() {
    $('#insert').val("Insert");
    $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
    $('#company').multiselect('refresh');
    $('#name').removeAttr('readonly');
  });

  // Edit roles
  $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function() {
    $("#company option").prop("selected", false);
    $("#name").attr('readonly', true);
    var data_id = $(this).attr("id");

    // Receive the current datas for the roles
    $.ajax({
      url: "fetchRole.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        'data_id': data_id
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#name').val(data.name);
        $('#hu').val(data.hu);
        $.each(data.companies, function(i, e) {
          $("#company option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
        });
        $('#company').multiselect('refresh');

        $('#data_id').val(data.id);
        $('#insert').val("Update");
        $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');
      }
    });
  });

  $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Update and insert
    $.ajax({
      url: "insertRole.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: $('#insert_form').serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#insert').val("Updating...");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
        $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');
        $('#role_table').html(data);
        location.reload();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: May be in your `insertRole.php` file you are checking condition based on `data_id`. Please check in that file by printing, what you are exactly getting in all scenarios (insert, update)

Comment: The insertRole.php file is good. My problem is that if I add a new row after I close the edit modal, it's update the row instead of insert a new one. But if I refresh the page then I add a new row, it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one thing make `data_id` field value blank when you are closing the modal

```
 $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $("#data_id").val("");
 })
```

Maybe it will help

or on click of `add new` button do the same

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('#insert').val("Insert");
    $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
    $('#company').multiselect('refresh');
    $("#data_id").val("");
    $('#name').removeAttr('readonly');
  });
```